# Can you limit what React components an MDX page will render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, mdxjs

I'm wondering if there's a straight forward approach to creating allowed components and blocked components on an [MDX JS](https://mdxjs.com) page (Markdown with JSX included). I'd like to use MDX for user generated content and realize there are a lot of security issues around doing so; any tips for doing so are appreciated.